# how can we retrieve language set in the browser using angularJS? Is there a way?

Tags: angularjs

I can make use of $translate.use() in case of setting the preferred language in my code.
What if I change the language from english to french in my browser, How can I access the language key from my angularJS code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigator.language to get the language set in the browser

```
navigator.language
```

To get a list of languages supported by the user:

```
navigator.languages
```

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why window.navigator.language works on Firefox and doesn't work on Chrome? Am using window.navigator.language in FF and window.navigator.language[0] on chrome. Only then it detects.